# Clojure. What is 'banana? How is that different from "banana"?

Tags: clojure

Follow along with me at the Clojure REPL:

```
(def apos 'banana)  ; "apostropied" banana.
=> #'thic.core/apos
apos
=> banana
(def quo "banana")  ; "quoted" banana.
=> #'thic.core/quo
quo
=> "banana"
```

Clearly banana and "banana" are not the same. I GET that "banana" is a String, but what is *banana*?

When I 'type' them, I get:

```
type apos
=> #object[clojure.core$type 0x69085742 "clojure.core$type@69085742"]
=> banana

type quo
=> #object[clojure.core$type 0x69085742 "clojure.core$type@69085742"]
=> "banana"
```

So banana and "banana" are the same TYPE of thing?

To add to my confusion, at the REPL I get this:

```
(type apos)            ; Add a pair of parents.
=> clojure.lang.Symbol ; apos becomes a Symbol.
(type quo)             ; and
=> java.lang.String    ; quo becomes a String.
```

What am I seeing here?
banana (without the quotes) is a "symbol" and "banana" (with the quotes) is a "string"?
apos is a Symbol and quo is a String?

After many attempts, I am still hung up on Symbol vs. Symbol Value. SO 20th Century. :-)

Comment: `type apos` is a red herring. You are evaluating two totally separate expressions, `type` and `apos`. The repl prints their values in order. To call the `type` function on `apos`, you must use parens, as with any function call in Clojure.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to consult this list of [Clojure documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).  In particular, see

- Clojure for the Brave & True
- Getting Clojure

As for your question, `'foo` is the symbol composed of the 3 letters `foo`, while `"foo"` is a string composed of the 3 letters `foo`.  You normally don't need to use symbols as data in your code, unless you are doing something advanced.

Clojure also has keywords like `:foo`. It is composed of 3 letters `foo`. The colon acts like the quote in front of a symbol.

A string is used just like in other languages.  A symbol or keyword is not allowed to have spaces, so they don't need a trailing quote or colon, and Clojure leaves it off for simplicity.

When you see a plain symbol `foo` in the code (without a leading quote) it acts as a variable just like in Java, etc.

A string is meant to contain user data of any type.  A keyword is used to represent program control information like `:left` or `:right`, instead of a "magic" number, so these are similar to an `enum` in Java.